# BizTalk SSO issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

Since a couple of days ago, after we restarted the BizTalk server, we started getting the following warning  messages (yellow) in the EventLog every 5 minutes.

> Internal error: Failed to refresh tokens. Details: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.BizTalk.TokenStore.BizTalkTokenStore' threw an exception. ---> Microsoft.BizTalk.TokenStore.TokenStoreException: Internal error: An error occurred attempting to verify the SSO secret server. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database. See the event log (on computer 'OURSERVERNAME') for more details.

> at Microsoft.EnterpriseSingleSignOn.Interop.ISSOAdmin.GetGlobalInfo(Int32& flags, Int32& auditAppDeleteMax, Int32& auditMappingDeleteMax, Int32& auditNtpLookupMax, Int32& auditXpLookupMax, Int32& ticketTimeout, Int32& credCacheTimeout, String& secretServer, String& SSOAdminGroup, String& affiliateAppMgrGroup)
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.TokenStore.SSOHelper.IsMasterSecretServer()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.TokenStore.SSOHelper.IsMasterSecretServer()
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.TokenStore.BizTalkTokenStore..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.TokenStore.BizTalkTokenStore.UpdateIdentifiersListAndUserInfoAsync(EventLog tokenStoreEvent)
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.TokenStore.Service.TokenRefreshService.<RefreshTimer_Tick>d__11.MoveNext()

I am still investigating to see where the problem is, but I would appreciate if someone knows more about this issue and assist me.

I checked if the BizTalk service user is still in the right groups and I tried to find any missing parts in the BizTalk Server Configuration tool, but I couldn't see what has changed since the restart.

Comment: Use DTCPing to check connectivity to the SSO Database.  Check to see if the Windows Firewall is on, if so try disabling it. or enabling the MSDTC rules.

Comment: Thank you Dijkgraaf, 
I have all installed in the same machine and that should work by default.
I'm foxed with this issue! At least it doesn't stop the service running, but I have to fix it nevertheless.
Thanks again, Dimi

Comment: Is this a new install?  What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: Not a new install, this server is running for over a year now with BizTalk 2020. This is running on Windows Server 2019 Datacentre (version 10.0.17763).

Comment: Did you get any further?  You could try deleting the Host Instance and Host and re-creating it, that is what I did once when I had another issue with SSO https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2018/11/09/biztalkserverapplication-host-instance-enterprise-single-sign-on-access-denied-errors/  Otherwise you might try restoring the secret from a backup (which you hopefully made)

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf, I solved it at the end. I saved the backup password somewhere safe and I couldn't find it! When I remembered where it was at the end, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Restore the secret from a backup, which you hopefully made.